# Ionic 2 OnPause and OnResume the previous page is not maintained?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

I am using the `sidemenu` template.

> ionic start tempName sidemenu --v2 --ts

I opened Page Two and then pressed the back button of mobile the application went to hidden. I hope in this case `onPause` activity is used.

When I resume again the Page Two is changed as Page One. When `onResume()` activity the previous state is not restored.

Can you please help me to resolve this.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionic 2 has its own [lifecycle events](http://blog.ionic.io/navigating-lifecycle-events/).

It does not follow android activity lifecycle. This is because the app will run on top of the `webview` which will be called by a single activity.

Navigation in ionic is handled by a [NavController](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) and has its own lifecycle methods.

Along with this, each page is also an angular component which follows  angular`s component [lifecycle](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html).

One can use a lifecycle method of either NavController or Angular component depending on the scenario.

Comment: Correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

actually the answer above is not entirely correct.
you can achieve that by injecting the [Platform](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform) instance into your app.component and then subcrive to event emitters for [Pause](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#pause) and [Resume](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#resume)

NOTE: you won't be able to see/test these web running this in the browser with ionic serve . you'll need to build and deploy on an emulator or device